# Reading a number and a letter from the input and storing it as a letter and a number separately in c

Tags: c

Suppose I get an input such as q3 from the user. I need to take this as input and store q as a letter separately and 3 as a number. Please show me how to do this in c using code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char str[] = "q3";
    char    ch;
    int     num;
    sscanf(str,"%c%d",&ch,&num);
    printf("char: '%c'  num: '%d'\n", ch, num);
    return 0;
}
```

N.B.  Watch the ampersands (&) in the sscanf().  Forgetting to put those in is a really common coding mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char line[BUFSIZ];
  char c;
  int n;

  printf("Enter: ");
  fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);  // read a line of input

  c = line[0];  // put first letter from line into c

  n = atoi(line + 1);  // interpret second letter onwards as an integer

  printf("Letter: %c\n", c);
  printf("Number: %d\n", n);

  return 0;
}
```